# AngularJS - scope is not rendering the variables in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below AngularJS code.

The current time is not displayed after executing the below code:

```
<html ng-app="a">

<head>
    <title>Clock App</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Clock Application</h1>
    <div ng-controller="t"></div>
    <p> The current time is </p>
    <p ng-bind="timeString"></p>
    <p>{{50+3}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var d = angular.module("a", []);
        d.controller("t", function ($scope) {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            $scope.timeString = currentDate.toTimeString();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `timeString` actually has a value? I.e. log it in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Keep the controller to parent tag. Then it will work.

Corrected code below:

```html
<html ng-app="a">

<head>
    <title>Clock App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="t">
    <h1>Clock Application</h1>
    <div></div>
    <p> The current time is </p>
    <p ng-bind="timeString"></p>
    <p>{{50+3}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var d = angular.module("a", []);
        d.controller("t", function ($scope) {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            $scope.timeString = currentDate.toTimeString();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `timeString` value is not binding because the `ng-bind` is not aware of the `$scope.timeString`, since it is not inside the controller.

Try this

```
<div ng-controller="t">
    <p> The current time is </p>
    <p ng-bind="timeString"></p>
    <p>{{50+3}}</p>
</div>
```

```html
<html ng-app="a">

<head>
    <title>Clock App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Clock Application</h1>
    <div ng-controller="t">
    <p> The current time is </p>
    <p ng-bind="timeString"></p>
    <p>{{50+3}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var d = angular.module("a", []);
        d.controller("t", function ($scope) {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            $scope.timeString = currentDate.toTimeString();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```